# A story about time changing and everyone getting younger

Tags: story-identification

Main character is named Soames who narrates the story. The story is set in England and Soames starts as an old man. Another character (possibly a doctor) is a thoroughly unlikable person but Soames eventually adopts him when he gets too young to look after himself.

Comment: You've not provided too many points there, take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) and see if you can [edit] in any more details.